# How to add values to Dictionary with a list of dictionaries inside

Tags: c#, dictionary

Hello I'm trying to add values to this complex object. I'm trying to turn this object into JSON using JSON.Net.

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>> MyList 
    = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>>();
```

The end result should look something like this: `{
   "Documents": [
      {
         "Title": ,
         "DatePublished": ,
         "DocumentURL": ,
         "ThumbnailURL": ,
         "Abstract": ,
         "Sector": "",
         "Country": [
            ""
         ],
         "Document Type": ""
      }`
I have tried this but didn't work:

```
MyList["Dictionary"][0].Add("test", 4);
```

Comment: Please could you post your tried code? what problem you got?

Comment: And why do you need to have a Dictionary of a List of a Dictionary? Isn't there a better, more readable option, maybe?

Comment: Just start on the outside an work your way in.  Add an item to the outer collection in which you create a collection one level down, then do the same for the next level, and then you can add items to that lowermost level.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness this is my first time actually asking a question on here. In the future I will be more descriptive of my problem. Thank you everybody.

Comment: what didn't work? the code you have is correct (provided that you have already added a list object to the 'Dictionary' key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `Dictionary<string, int> dictA` you can add items to this via

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictA = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictA.Add("SomeString", 99);
```

Then to add this dictionary to your `List<Dictionary<string, int>>` use the following

```
List<Dictionary<string, int>> dictList = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();
dictList.Add(dictA);
```

Now you can add this to your `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>> myList` object via

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>> myList = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>>();
myList.Add("SomeString", dictList);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, here's a sample loop which shows how to use [`Dictionary.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx) and the [Collection Initalizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531208.aspx):

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>> MyList = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>>();

foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(1, 100))
{
    var list = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();
    foreach (int ii in Enumerable.Range(1, 100))
        list.Add(new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "Item " + ii, ii } });
    MyList.Add("Item " + i, list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyList.Add("key1", new List<Dictionary<string, int>());
MyList["key1"].Add(new Dictionary<String, int>());
```

etc.

Will need more detail from you to give much more than that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it looks complex, it really is quite simple:

Your dictionary takes keys of `string`, and values of `List<Dictionary<string, int>>`. So to add a *value*, that value should always be of type `List<Dictionary<string, int>>`.