# How to add items in dictionary in which value is list of class?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am having a below dictionary :

```
Dictionary<string, List<Coordinates>> Coordinates = new Dictionary<string,List<Coordinates>>();

 public class Coordinates
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal range { get; set; }
        //other properties
    }
```

Now I am trying to add coordinates to my dictionary for specific region id and if same coordinates id comes then I don't want to add it.

Below is my web service method:

```
public string MyMethod(string coordinateId, string regionId)
        { 
           var coordinates = Coordinates.Where(ed => (ed.Key == regionId)).SelectMany(ed => ed.Value).ToList();

           var coordinatesExist = coordinates.Any(ed => ed.Id.ToString() == id);
           if (!Coordinates.ContainsKey(regionId) && !coordinatesExist)
            {
                   //here i want to add it but as it is list of my class i dont know how to add it  
                   Coordinates.Add(regionId, ?????);
            }
            else
            {
               return "This coordinate id already exist for this region id";
            }
        }
```

I have check below link but those answers are with the list of string or with an array but not with the list of class:

[c# dictionary How to add multiple values for single key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089850/c-sharp-dictionary-how-to-add-multiple-values-for-single-key)

[How to add values to Dictionary with a list of dictionaries inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881960/how-to-add-values-to-dictionary-with-a-list-of-dictionaries-inside)

**Sample Data** :

```
Region Id = 100
Coordinate Id = 10,20,30

Region Id = 200
Coordinate Id = 10,20,30
```

- 1st call to Mymethod with RegionId = 100 and coordinate id =10 then I would like to have in my dictionary:**Key = 100 , value = 10**
- 2nd call to Mymethod with RegionId = 100 and coordinate id =20 then I would like to have in my dictionary:**Key = 100 , value = 20**
- 3rd call to Mymethod with RegionId = 100 and coordinate id =20 then I would like to have in my dictionary:
  **I don't want to add this as 20 coordinate id already exist for regionId = 100**

Comment: basically `new List<Coordinates>(){yourCoorDinates}>`

Comment: is it `Coordinates.Add(regionId, Coordinates.Where(ed => (ed.Key == regionId)).ToList());`

Comment: Btw its better to name your class `Coordinate` otherwise it might confuse yourself and other people that the class itself is a list of multiple Coordinate(s).

Comment: @Learning - aint this working? `Coordinates.Add(regionId, Coordinates.Where(ed => (ed.Key == regionId)).ToList())` where `Cordinates` in `Coordinates.Whe..` is list List of Class not enum

Comment: @Developer:Ok let me try what you posted.Thanks :)

Comment: Your class name `Coordinates` and dictionary variable name `Coordinates` are the same. This could cause ambiguity!

Answer (score 1):

Say your class name is `Coordinate` and your dictionary is `Coordinates`

Basically:

```
Coordinates.Add(
  new List<Coordinate>()
  { 
    new Coordinate()
    {
      Id = coordinateId
    }
  }
); //You can remove all the whitespaace
```

The problem is this way (Since your code checks on if there already exists a list for the key in the dictionary) you will always only have 1 entry in your list.

So why not changes to a `Dictionary<string, Coordinates>`?

In json terms:

```
this is what you do:
{  "key" : [Coordinate] }

why not?
{  "key" : Coordinate }

Or are you trying to achieve? 
{  "key" : [Coordinate, Coordinate, Coordinate] }
```

## Answer update

So you do, want the later: `{  "key" : [Coordinate, Coordinate, Coordinate] }`.

You have a List inside each Dictionary entry. If a dictionary is a list of keys and values, Say in 1 dimension a List inside a dictionary is a 2 dimensional Array.

The thing is here. You need to break it up in 2 steps:

1. Check if the regionId key already exists in the dictionary (This means already 1 coordinate is in there(
2. If not: make a new list with the first coordinates.
3. If it does, check if the CoordinateId already exists, if not add it to the list.

### Solution

```
public string MyMethod(string coordinateId, string regionId)
{
    if (!Coordinates.ContainsKey(regionId))
    {
        oordinates.Add(regionId, new Coordinate() {Id = regionId});
    }
    else
    {
        //Get the list of coordinates out of the dictionary for its region
        var list = Coordinates[regionId];
        if(list.Any(cor=> cor.Id == coordinateId))
        {   //Check if any of the coordinates have the same Id
            return "This coordinate id already exist for this region id";

        } else
        {  //Otherwise we add it to the list.
            lists.Add(new Coordinate() { Id = regionId})
        }

    }
    return "added";
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some code related to your updated answer as because i never used this kind of structure with dictionary

Comment: @Learning, I did, but i shouldn't have. You need to understand this basic stuff, not just copy paste it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct data structure, a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<Coordinates>>`. [Add the `Equals` and `GetHashCode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317582/correct-way-to-override-equals-and-gethashcode) methods to `Coordinates` that compare on the id.

That way you can just [add another object to the `HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx) and it will only get added if it wasn't already there.

Comment: Can you please post some code related to what you are saying.so that by taking reference of that i can try something

Comment: Added a couple of links.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
`Coordinates.Add(regionId, new List<Coordinates> { new Coordinates { Id = id, Range = ??? } });`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
Coordinates.Add(regionId, new List<Coordinates>()
                        {
                          new Coordinates(){Id=1,range=10},
                          new Coordinates(){Id=2,range=110},
                          new Coordinates(){Id=3,range=1140}
                       });
```

If you want to initialize such dictonary means you can do like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Coordinates>> Coordinates = new Dictionary<string, List<Coordinates>>()
{ 
    {"ID1", new List<Coordinates>()
          {
            new Coordinates(){Id=1,range=10},
            new Coordinates(){Id=2,range=110},
            new Coordinates(){Id=3,range=1140}
          }
    },
    {"ID2", new List<Coordinates>()
          {
            new Coordinates(){Id=1,range=10},
            new Coordinates(){Id=2,range=110},
            new Coordinates(){Id=3,range=1140}
          }
    }
};
```